# Change default window layout of Vimspector

Tags: vim-windows, plugin-vimspector

When debugging with [Vimspector](https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector), I would love to customize the default window layout. I mainly want to have a wider view of the vimspector.Watches window on the left. I can do this after firing up a session by using `CTRL-W <`, `CTRL-W >` etc., but I would love to persistently change the default. I've checked Vimspector's [Readme](https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector) and [Configuration Options](https://puremourning.github.io/vimspector/configuration.html) based on the `.vimspector.config`, but couldn't find a way. Maybe I just missed something.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For just window sizes

[This experimental section](https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector#changing-the-default-window-sizes) says

> > Please Note: This customisation API is unstable, meaning that it may change at any time. I will endeavour to reduce the impact of this and announce changes in Gitter.
>
> The following options control the default sizes of the UI windows (all of them are numbers)
>
> - `g:vimspector_sidebar_width` (default: 50 columns): The width in columns of the left utility windows (variables, watches, stack trace)
> - `g:vimspector_bottombar_height` (default 10 lines): The height in rows of the output window below the code window.
>   Example:

```
let g:vimspector_sidebar_width = 75
let g:vimspector_bottombar_height = 15
```

### For more control

There's [this experimental section](https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector#advanced-ui-customisation) saying

> The above customisation of window sizes is limited intentionally to keep things simple. Vimspector also provides a way for you to customise the UI without restrictions, by running a `User` autocommand just after creating the UI or opening the terminal. This requires you to write some vimscript, but allows you to do things like:
>
> - Hide a particular window or windows
> - Move a particular window or windows
> - Resize windows
> - Have multiple windows for a particular buffer (say, you want 2 watch windows)
> - etc.
>
> You can essentially do anything you could do manually by writing a little vimscript code.
>
> The `User` autocommand is raised with pattern set with the following values:
>
> - `VimspectorUICreated:` Just after setting up the UI for a debug session
> - `VimspectorTerminalOpened:` Just after opening the terminal window for program input/output.
>
> The following global variable is set up for you to get access to the UI elements: `g:vimspector_session_windows`. This is a `dict` with the following keys:
>
> - `g:vimspector_session_windows.tagpage`: The tab page for the session
> - `g:vimspector_session_windows.variables`: Window ID of the variables window, containing the `vimspector.Variables` buffer.
> - `g:vimspector_session_windows.watches`: Window ID of the watches window, containing the `vimspector.Watches` buffer.
> - `g:vimspector_session_windows.stack_trace`: Window ID of the stack trade window containing the `vimspector.StackTrace` buffer.
> - `g:vimspector_session_windows.code`: Window ID of the code window.
> - `g:vimspector_session_windows.output`: Window ID of the output window.
>
> In addition, the following key is added when triggering the `VimspectorTerminalOpened` event:
>
> - `g:vimspector_session_windows.terminal`: Window ID of the terminal window

You'll probably find `win_id2win()`/`win_id2tabwin()` and `win_execute()` helpful if you go this route.